# Как получить анимированую SVG иконку в фон?

Tags: svg, анимация, css-animation

Подскажите, пожалуйста, есть ли возможность многократного получание SVG иконок с CSS анимацией на background псевдо класса? Приведу пример

```css
#icon_argee {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

.path {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #22AF4B;
  stroke-width: 2;
  stroke-miterlimit: 10;
  stroke-linecap: round;
}

.agree_line1 {
  stroke-dasharray: 19.586;
  stroke-dashoffset: 19.586;
  animation: dashLine .4s linear;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.agree_line2 {
  stroke-dasharray: 10.346;
  stroke-dashoffset: 10.346;
  animation: dashLine .4s linear;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes dashLine {
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}

.test {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 40px;
  width: 120px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.icon:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  content: "";
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: url("#icon_argee");
}
```

```html
<div class="test icon">Text</div>

<svg id="icon_argee">
  <use id="icon" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
   <path class="path agree_line1" d="M8.7,19 18.6,2.1"/>
   <path class="path agree_line2" d="M8.7,19 3.1,10.3"/>
  </use>
</svg>
```

Мне необходимо вставлять иконку с анимацией "роста" через класс .icon Это вообще реально ?

Comment: Почему у вас в коде `<use>`? Тут или `<g>` или что-то другое должно быть.